# Looking for a sci-fi about life after death

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story around 10 ago and haven't been able to find it ever since.

The hero of the story is a prolific scientist in some mathematical field, and he dies at around page 1. His soul is however conserved by "god", who then proceeds to reveal the big plan. Basically the "god" collects the souls of great minds, and everyone else just fades into oblivion. These souls then have to work for eternity and help "god" find out where he came from. In the end of the story the hero refuses to cooperate and swears to spend his eternity finding a way to destroy "god".

Please help me find it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like ["The Last Answer" by Isaac Asimov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Answer). Summary from wikipedia:

> In the story, an atheist physicist Murray Templeton dies of a heart
>   attack and is greeted by a being of supposedly infinite knowledge.
>   This being, referred to as the Voice, tells the physicist the nature
>   of his life after death, as a nexus of electromagnetic forces. The
>   Voice concludes that, while by all human ideas he most resembles God,
>   he is contrary to any human conception of the being. The Voice informs
>   him that all of the Universe is a creation of the Voice, the purpose
>   of which was to result in intelligent life which, after death, the
>   Voice could cull for his own purposes—to wit, Templeton, like all the
>   others, is to think, for all eternity, so as to amuse him. Conversing
>   with the Voice, Templeton learns that the Voice desires original
>   thoughts by which to please His curiosity, but surrenders that yes, in
>   fact, if He so desired, the Voice could happen upon those thoughts
>   himself, of his own effort.
>
> The physicist is appalled by the idea of thinking and discovering for
>   no reason but to amuse a being capable of easily out-thinking him with
>   a bit of effort. Templeton decides, therefore, to direct his thoughts
>   towards spiting the Voice, whom he regards as a capricious entity, by
>   destroying himself. The Voice dissuades him by pointing out it is
>   easily within His power to reconstitute Templeton's disembodied form
>   with that method of suicide, whatever it may be, disabled. Through
>   further inquiry, Templeton discovers that the Voice (in a classic
>   counterargument to the logical regression of the First Cause argument
>   for the existence of god) has no knowledge of his own creation.
>   Templeton realizes that this, in turn, suggests he has no knowledge of
>   his own destruction, and concludes that the only vengeance for this
>   tyranny is also the ultimate vengeance, and resolves to destroy the
>   Voice.
>
> At this epiphany and decision, the Voice reflects satisfaction,
>   thinking that Templeton reached this conclusion rather faster than
>   most of the countless beings currently trapped in the same condition,
>   implying that the one thing the Voice truly wishes to learn from his
>   thralls is the method by which he can be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! That's exactly what I was looking for haha best day of my life!
I've found "The Last Question" by Isaac Asimov and couldn't possibly imagine there was also "The Last Answer". I would cease to exist if I were Murray Templeton. That's for sure haha

Answer (score 1):

How about "The Years of Rice and Salt" by Kim Stanley Robinson. It follows a group of people through multiple reincarnations through about 700 hundred years of an alternate history of our planet. One in which about 99% of Europe had died off in the black plague. Interesting story-line, which uses the lives between lives as part of the main theme.